# Zend_Form_Element_Captcha Not Working

Tags: php, zend-framework

Apparently this is a common problem but I have not been able to figure out how to get a Zend Captcha Image to show up, it will create the image and it will create the hidden element but the image tag never shows up, does anyone have a solution??

Here is the code that doesn't work:

```
<?php

class Application_Form_Contact extends Zend_Form
{

    public function init()
    {
        /* Form Elements & Other Definitions Here ... */
        $this->setAction('/contact/')->setMethod('post');

        $element = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('name');
        $element->setLabel('Name:')
                    ->setRequired(true)
                    ->addFilter('HtmlEntities');
        $this->addElement($element);

        $element = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('phone');
        $element->setLabel('Phone:')
                    ->setRequired(true)
                    ->addFilter('HtmlEntities');
        $this->addElement($element);

        $element = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('email');
        $element->setLabel('Email:')    
                    ->setRequired(true)
                    ->addValidator('EmailAddress', true)
                    ->addFilter('StripTags')
                    ->addFilter('HtmlEntities')
                    ->addFilter('StringToLower')
                    ->addFilter('StringTrim');
        $this->addElement($element);


        $comments = $this->createElement('textarea', 'comments')
                    ->setLabel('Comments:')
                    ->setRequired(true)
                    ->setOptions(array('style'=>'width:95%;'))
                    ->addFilter('StripTags')
                    ->addFilter('HtmlEntities')
                    ->addFilter('StringTrim');

        $this->addElement($comments);

        $captcha= new Zend_Form_Element_Captcha('captcha', array(
                'id'=>'captchas',
                'title'=>'Security Check.',
                'captcha' => array(
                'captcha' => 'Image',
                'required' => true,
                'font'=> PUBLIC_PATH . '/verdana.ttf',
                'wordlen'=>'4',
                'width'=>'80',
                'height'=>'50',
                'ImgAlign'=>'left',
                'imgdir'=> PUBLIC_PATH . '/images/captcha/',
                'DotNoiseLevel'=>'0',
                'LineNoiseLevel'=>'0', 
                'Expiration'=>'1000',
                'fontsize'=>'16'
                )));


        $this->addElement($captcha);
        $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
        $submit->setLabel('Send'); 
        $this->addElement($submit);




    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've only got two ideas that might help:

- Check to make sure your GD extension is enabled in php.

> It requires the GD extension compiled with TrueType or Freetype support. Currently, the Zend_Captcha_Image adapter can only generate PNG images.

- you may want to specify the ***imgUrl =>***

> setImgUrl($imgUrl) and getImgUrl() allow you to specify the relative path to a CAPTCHA image to use for HTML markup. The default is "/images/captcha/".

also just for information you don't need to set the element as ***required*** as the captcha is always required.

> As noted, the captcha adapter itself acts as a validator for the element. Additionally, the NotEmpty validator is not used, and the element is marked as required. In most cases, you should need to do nothing else to have a captcha present in your form.

Try to edit your captcha down to bare bones

```
$captcha = new Zend_Form_Element_Captcha('Captcha', array(
            'captcha' => array(
                'captcha' => 'Image',
                'wordLen' => 6,
                'timeout' => 300,
                'width' => 300,
                'height' => 100,
                'imgUrl' => '/captcha',
                'imgDir' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public/captcha',
                'font' => APPLICATION_PATH .  '/../public/fonts/LiberationSansRegular.ttf')));
```

just get anything to work then add back what you need 'till you find the problem. I suspect you have a problem with one of your paths.
Start with the APPLICATION_PATH constant then change to PUBLIC_PATH if you feel it's better.

Comment: When I run phpinfo it shows GD enabled with freetype support, I have tried setting the **imgUrl** in many different ways but nothing has worked...

Answer (score 0):

check your file permissions; I had to give group write access before the image would write.

Comment: It turned out to be some whitespace before the **<?php** tag in the form class that was keeping the right headers being sent for the image.